# Добавить переносы в список value

Tags: jquery, jquery-form

Доброго времени суток, помогите решить задачу. Сделал скрипт на лендинге который по кнопке отправляет товар к корзину. Потом отдельно код $(".cart-list").append(name + "
"); собирает список товара по названию в Input и список с инпута отправляется на почту через php... только вот .val и .text собирают только текст а нужно что бы шло вместе с br. подскажите как решить, спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно и `html` теги используйте функцию  `.html`

Comment: Пробовал, не действует html почему то

Comment: var list = $(".cart-list").html();
   var remove = "<img src='img/icon/del.png' class='remove' alt=''>";
   var cena = "<span class='eachPrice'>" + (parseFloat($(this).children(".item-detail").children(".price").text())) + "</span>";
   var cena2 = "<span class='eachPrice2'>" + (parseFloat($(this).children(".item-detail").children(".price").text())) + "</span>";
   $("#list-item").append("<div class='tli'>" + remove + "<p>" + name + "&#09;  &#09;" + "</p>"  + "<span>" + cena + "р." + "<span>" + "</div>" );
   $(".cart-list").append(name + "<br>");
   $(".list").val(list);

Answer (score 1):

Простой пример:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  alert($('#test').html());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test"><b>test</b></div>
```